# How to hide/show text with Javascript - link behavior

Tags: javascript

I have just started learning JavaScript and I need some help. 
I have got an HTML file and a CSS file in which I am NOT to make any changes. 
With Javascript I have to add 2 links which will hide and show the paragraphs with class "show" .
When you open the HTML file in your browser , the paragraphs in question should be hidden.

I ve read almost everything that is written here about the hide/show text methods but I still can't solve the problem and I cant seem to get my links to work properly.

This is what I've got so far in my JavaScript code:

```
window.onload = function(){
var par = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
var parArray = [];


for (var i=0 ; i < par.length; i++) {
    if (par[i].getAttribute("class") === "show") {
        parArray.push(par[i]);
        par[i].style.display = "none";
        }  
    }

    console.log(par);
    console.log(parArray);

for (i=0 ; i<parArray.length; i++) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    var linkText = document.createTextNode("Show more information");
    a.appendChild(linkText);
    a.title = "Show more information";
    a.href = "#";   
    parArray[i].parentNode.appendChild(a);  
}
}
```

I want to make a function which will add the proper behavior to my links (show the text and change the link text to hide OR hide the text and change the link text to show) and then use the onclick event handler to call the function.

Here is my html code as well:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Javascript Hidden textarea</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <div class="post">
                <h3>
                    Title
                </h3>
                <p class="author">
                     paragraph One
                </p>        
            <aside>
                JavaScript
            </aside>
                <p>
                    paragraph two
                </p>
                <p class="show">
                    ...We must hide this paragraph.
                </p>    
        </div>
        <div class="post">
                <h3>
                    Title
                </h3>
                <p class="author">
                     paragraph One
                </p>        
            <aside>
                JavaScript
            </aside>
                <p>
                    paragraph two
                </p>
                <p class="show">
                    ...We must hide this paragraph.
                </p>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="hidetext.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

THANK YOU in advance!

Comment: Why are your `for` loops nested? Can you modify the HTML? Just add `style="display: none;"` to the hidden pages to default them to false. You also have no way to link a specific button with a specific `show` element, you'll have to add something for the `onclick` handler to target. Have you considered using jQuery also?

Comment: I am not supposed to use jQuery and I cant change my HTML code or my CSS code. Just the JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
function toggle() {  
    // Select all the p elements with class = show.  
    var par = document.querySelectorAll('p.show');
    // The link to show the hidden p.
    var linkShow = document.getElementById('linkShow');
    // The link to hide the shown p.
    var linkHide = document.getElementById('linkHide');

    for (var i = 0; i < par.length; i++) {
        // p current style display.
        var style = par[i].style.display;

        // Toggle the p style display.
        par[i].style.display = 
            (!style || style == '' ? 'none' : 
             (style == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none'));
    }

    if (linkShow != null && 
        linkHide != null) {
        // linkShow current style display.
        style = linkShow.style.display;

        // Toggle both links style display.
        linkShow.style.display = (style == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none');
        linkHide.style.display = style;
    }
}

window.onload = function () {
    // First run.
    toggle();

    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    var text = document.createTextNode('Show more information');

    link.appendChild(text);
    link.title = 'Show more information';
    link.href = '#';
    link.id = 'linkShow';   
    link.addEventListener('click', toggle);

    container.appendChild(link);

    link = document.createElement('a');
    text = document.createTextNode('Hide information');

    link.appendChild(text);
    link.title = 'Hide information';
    link.href = '#';
    link.id = 'linkHide';
    link.style.display = 'none';
    link.addEventListener('click', toggle);

    container.appendChild(link);
};
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/g0vq6ufL/2/)

**UPDATE**

Reading your question more carefully, I think that's what you're trying to do:

```
function toggle(first) {
    var par = document.querySelectorAll('p.show');

    // Just on the first run.
    if (first === true) {
        for (var i = 0; i < par.length; i++) {
            var style = par[i].style.display;

            par[i].style.display = 
                (!style || style == '' ? 'none' : 
                 (style == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none'));
        }

        return;
    }

    // The element to toggle is coming as a data attribute
    // data-rel that's set in the clicked link.
    var ix = parseInt(this.getAttribute('data-rel'));
    var elToToggle = par[ix];
    var style = par[ix].style.display;
    elToToggle.style.display = (style == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none');

    var linkShow = document.getElementById('linkShow_' + ix.toString());
    style = linkShow.style.display;    
    linkShow.style.display = 
        (!style || style == '' ? 'none' :
         (style == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none'));

    var linkHide = document.getElementById('linkHide_' + ix.toString());
    style = linkHide.style.display;
    linkHide.style.display = 
        (!style || style == '' ? 'none' :
         (style == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none'));
}

window.onload = function () {
    toggle(true);

    var par = document.querySelectorAll('p.show');

    for (var i = 0; i < par.length; i++) {
        var container = par[i].parentNode;
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        var text = document.createTextNode('Show more information');

        link.appendChild(text);
        link.title = 'Show more information';
        link.href = '#';
        link.id = 'linkShow_' + i.toString();
        link.setAttribute('data-rel', i);
        link.addEventListener('click', toggle, false);

        container.appendChild(link);

        link = document.createElement('a');
        text = document.createTextNode('Hide information');

        link.appendChild(text);
        link.title = 'Hide information';
        link.href = '#';
        link.id = 'linkHide_' + i.toString();
        link.setAttribute('data-rel', i);
        link.style.display = 'none';
        link.addEventListener('click', toggle, false);

        container.appendChild(link);
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/g0vq6ufL/3/)

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot. I would be grateful if you could explain the logic of the for loop and the if loop in the toggle function. I know that its a ternary operation thing and I can "read" it but cant understand really how you thought of it. Thanks again. :)

Comment: `.querySelectorAll()` will bring you a collection of elements satisfying the selector. I just looped through this list.

Comment: On the first run, the `p` won't have any style `display` defined, and as you want them to start hidden, I then set it to `none`. When you toggle using the links, I just check what's the current style display and toggle it: `none` <=> `block`.